# get witdh of div element (parent overflow hidden)

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, flexbox

Get the with of a div which is partly hidden by overflow hidden.

I have a div container which contains 3 divs

the div container is set to flex en only the last div is growing in size so it fills up the space in the container.
The container has the property overflow hidden.

The last div contains dynamic data that wil fill up the div and will be partly hidden. I need to know what the size(width) of the div is within the container.

I tried several methods like offsetwith, clientwidth & getboundingclientrect().width.

All return the width of the div with the hidden part.
I need the width whitout the hidden part.

```
I created an example on codepen.
https://codepen.io/Babulaas/pen/GObgxb
```

(I use (angular2) typescript in my project but didnt know how to use this in codepen

Comment: try `offsetWidth`

Comment: If you post the relevant markup with the code you currently have issues with we could copy it into a fiddle or similar to try out what could work for you instead of suggesting hypotheticals in the hope it might work for you.

Comment: You can use a calculation like `[parent width] - [all children except hidden one width sum]`.

Comment: please share the snippet/code so we could help you

Comment: I added an copepen example to the question

Comment: Don't circumvent the requirement of posting code sample within the question by adding the external link as code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you have to get all div elements inside the div with hidden css parameter and just adding up all width of them

Using jQuery

```
var totalWidth = 0
  //this get all div element inside component
  $('.component > div').each(function(){
    totalWidth += $(this).width()
  })
  alert('total width of elements inside container "component": ' + totalWidth)
```

your codepen edited

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzJjBo

observation: this work because the inner elements of "component" are inline, you cant get the width of the "component" element adding the hidden part because the hidden part is not part of the width of "component" is part of the overflowed element. the offset method or outerWidth as is called in jQuery get you the width of the element adding the padding, margin and border, not the hidden part because is not part of the element.